# How to verify multiple server's root password using bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I've two text files one with list of server name's, another file with their root password (Unique password)

I have to check all server root password by logging to individual servers. but the issue is, by default ssh root login is disabled. Hence i have to login via my normal user(Test) and switch as root and try the root password which is mentioned in the text file.

is there any way i can get this automated ? highly appreciate if anyone can help me out.

Comment: try `sshpass`. Keeping passwords in text files, and automating passwords are bad practice.

Comment: But sshpass will login as normal user. not sure how to verify after logging and verify root password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux passwords are stored in `/etc/shadow` files.
They're just hashed plain-text, no magic.
Take a look at python's `crypt.crypt()` function.

```
# change 'root' password to 'secret' (demo only)
$ echo root:secret | chpasswd
Password for 'root' changed

# get 'root' hashed password
$ grep root /etc/shadow
root:$6$YvK0oNOm$k.zELztgUM2LajbVGsqtp5I3mGP3clC6vL7rNdVCNfg2FUtLOnfb94Bn6acfCp4cQpXxSAZ1Zt55K8rAgQ3nT0:16673:0:::::

# verify hashed password is correct
$ python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("secret", "$6$YvK0oNOm$") == "$6$YvK0oNOm$k.zELztgUM2LajbVGsqtp5I3mGP3clC6vL7rNdVCNfg2FUtLOnfb94Bn6acfCp4cQpXxSAZ1Zt55K8rAgQ3nT0"'
True
```

You can collect shadow files from all servers, and verify them locally.
**WARNING:** Shadow files are very sensitive.

---

This is a simple solution.

**input.csv**

```
192.168.1.1,secret,$6$YvK0oNOm$k.zELztgUM2LajbVGsqtp5I3mGP3clC6vL7rNdVCNfg2FUtLOnfb94Bn6acfCp4cQpXxSAZ1Zt55K8rAgQ3nT0
192.168.1.2,pAssWd,$6$AbcdeFgh$1234fsXXXXXXXXXXXsqtp5I3mGP3clC6vL7rNdVCNfg2FUtLOnfb94Bn6acfCp4cQpXxSAZ1Zt55K8rAgQ3nT0
192.168.1.3,123456,$6$efsjdsix$8787sdfsdsdfsd232sqtp5I3mGP3clC6vL7rNdVCNfg2FUtLOnfb94Bn6acfCp4cQpXxSAZ1Zt55K8rAgQ3nT0
```

**check.py**

```
import csv, crypt
for i, j, k in csv.reader(open('input.csv')):
    if crypt.crypt(j, k) != k:
        print i
```

**result**

```
$ python check.py
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working i tested on a test box. I can able to get all shadow file's info from all servers.

But, after getting how can i  automate the verification process. Execuse me i am very new to scripting. any leads will help me out.

Comment: @Saravanan Try to generate a csv file which contains 3 columns: `ipaddress,password,hash`, then call `crypt()` for each line, print bad lines.

Comment: Thanks Kev, as suggested i had created CSV file with Server Ipaddress,password and hash (shadow file). 
how can i call crypt () function. I'm so sorry im not sure how to call function. I tried to find answer via Google and stackoverflow. but, ended you here asking you. can you please let me know how to invoke the hash and password in python command ?

Comment: Thanks for the response, i tried your updated script to verify root password locally on one of a test box. But, seems My results are wrong.

Input.csv
192.168.1.100,wrongpassword,$6$PiM.5FblFtp2iEX9$7y.SmYHunzzznZrEUd15WCOuWWmDWlnLbOj7sIiHsfaAKYqns9BI7eCKUW849G.qUJ44j4ZFVloQ6D3em2Oz9

# python check.py
192.168.1.100

Seems, I've got a wrong result. the password for that test box is "redhat". Am i doing anything wrong ? correct me if i did any mistake.

Comment: @Saravanan You need to run this script on linux platform. Please make two testcases (right + wrong). It will print wrong one. If everything is ok, it'll print nothing.

Comment: I tried on my Redhat 6.3 box. i tried both right and wrong test cases.

Comment: Did you run my testcase? If it print different result, then something is wrong.

Comment: Noice that the length of salt is different: `$6$12345678$`. Maybe this is problem.

Comment: I tried your Test case too and added my test server details on the same file.
# cat input.csv
192.168.1.2,pAssWd,$6$AbcdeFgh$1234fsXXXXXXXXXXXsqtp5I3mGP3clC6vL7rNdVCNfg2FUtLOnfb94Bn6acfCp4cQpXxSAZ1Zt55K8rAgQ3nT0
192.168.1.3,123456,$6$efsjdsix$8787sdfsdsdfsd232sqtp5I3mGP3clC6vL7rNdVCNfg2FUtLOnfb94Bn6acfCp4cQpXxSAZ1Zt55K8rAgQ3nT0
192.168.1.100,edhat,$6$PiM.5FblFtp2iEX9$7y.SmYHunzzznZrEUd15WCOuWWmDWlnLbOj7sIiHsfaAKYqns9BI7eCKUW849G.qUJ44j4ZFVloQ6D3em2Oz9
# python check.py
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.100